# How can I iterate through a nested python dictionary with a recursive lamba function?

Tags: python, recursion, lambda

I have a dictionary like the one below.  I want to iterate through and create multilevel hierarchical index DataFrame.

```
d={1e-06: {1: {'conv': [1, 2.0, 2.0, 1]},
         2: {'pool': [2.0, 2.0, 1, 1], 'stride': [1, 2.0, 2.0, 1]},
         3: {'conv': [1, 2.0, 2.0, 1]},
         4: {'pool': [2.0, 2.0, 1, 1], 'stride': [1, 2.0, 2.0, 1]}}, 
 1e-05: {1: {'conv': [1, 2.0, 2.0, 1]},
         2: {'pool': [2.0, 2.0, 1, 1], 'stride': [1, 2.0, 2.0, 1]}, 
         3: {'conv': [1, 2.0, 2.0, 1]}, 
         4: {'pool': [2.0, 2.0, 1, 1], 'stride': [1, 2.0, 2.0, 1]}}}
```

I was playing around with some methods and found that the follow works.

```
a_list=lambda d: [a_list(v) if isinstance(v,dict) else v for k,v in d.items()]
```

yields

```
pd.DataFrame(a_list(d))
                    0                                     1  \
0  [[1, 2.0, 2.0, 1]]  [[2.0, 2.0, 1, 1], [1, 2.0, 2.0, 1]]   
1  [[1, 2.0, 2.0, 1]]  [[2.0, 2.0, 1, 1], [1, 2.0, 2.0, 1]]   

                    2                                     3  
0  [[1, 2.0, 2.0, 1]]  [[2.0, 2.0, 1, 1], [1, 2.0, 2.0, 1]]  
1  [[1, 2.0, 2.0, 1]]  [[2.0, 2.0, 1, 1], [1, 2.0, 2.0, 1]]
```

But, I am not sure if this is a **safe** use of the anonymous function `lambda`.

Is this usage improper in any way?

Can anyone provide any details of what is happening with the `lambda` function environments respective to the recursion?

### UPDATE

Going forward with that strategy, the following code creates the multilevel hierarchical DataFrame.

I still *would like to know* **if issues might arise**, if the nesting complexity of the dictionary increases.

---

**The Code**

Create the tuples for the multilevel index

```
g = lambda d,q:[ g(v,q+[k]) if isinstance(v,dict) else {tuple(q+[k]):v} for 
k,v in d.items()]
```

Unpivot the extraneous columns

```
g1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
        sum(            #flatten vertically
            sum(        #flatten horizontally
                g(d,[]),# call recursive lambda
                []),
            [])
     ).melt().dropna()  # unpivot
```

Get, create, use

```
g2 = list(g1['variable'])

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(g2)

g1.index = index

g1['value']

0.000001  1  conv      [1, 2.0, 2.0, 1]
          2  pool      [2.0, 2.0, 1, 1]
             stride    [1, 2.0, 2.0, 1]
          3  conv      [1, 2.0, 2.0, 1]
          4  pool      [2.0, 2.0, 1, 1]
             stride    [1, 2.0, 2.0, 1]
0.000010  1  conv      [1, 2.0, 2.0, 1]
          2  pool      [2.0, 2.0, 1, 1]
             stride    [1, 2.0, 2.0, 1]
          3  conv      [1, 2.0, 2.0, 1]
          4  pool      [2.0, 2.0, 1, 1]
             stride    [1, 2.0, 2.0, 1]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"? It would be better style to use a proper `def`, but apart from that...

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations -- "Always use a def statement instead of an assignment statement that binds a lambda expression directly to an identifier. Yes:

`def f(x): return 2*x` 
No:

 `f = lambda x: 2*x`"

Comment: by safe I mean no surprises: like the environments act differently for lambda's  than others.  So that at recurring levels lambda functions act as to be expected

Comment: the advantage I see here is the minimal code.  Have not see a one liner with same functionality.